# Getting 'Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again. (ligne 0).' on a normally working script

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

We've been using gmail accounts for some time even if we have a G Suite account. I'm migrating things little by little. I must say that I don't know a thing about coding. The script that I'm talking about here has been written by somebody else for my needs.

The script is for a custom function for Google Sheet. It works wonder on the gmail account, but when I'm trying to use it on my G Suite, I get an error:

> Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again. (ligne 0).

The script is as follows:

```
function getUniqueValues(rangeValues){
  /*
  Creates a column list of unique values sorted in descending order from input range.

  Args:
    rangeValues: The range of cells.

  Returns:
    A column list of values.
  */
  var valueSet = {};
  var valueArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < rangeValues.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rangeValues[i].length; j++){
      if(rangeValues[i][j] != ""){
        valueSet[rangeValues[i][j]] = "";
      }
    }
  }
  for(var key in valueSet){
    valueArray.push(key);
  }
  return valueArray.sort();
}
```

As I said, it works on my Gmail account, but not on my G Suite account.